# Mongod db nested inside nested element match and projection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

my document structure is:

```
db={
  "booking": [
    {
      "_id": "5a934e000102030405000000",
      "cart": [
        {
          "_id": "5a934e000102030405000001",
          "productId": "5934e00010203040500031",
          "timeSlots": [
            {
              "_id": "5a934e00010203040500022",
              "spots": 10
            },
            {
              "_id": "5a934e00010203040540002",
              "spots": 2
            },
            {
              "_id": "5a934e00010203040505002",
              "spots": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": "9934e00010203040500r33",
          "productId": "9934e00010203040500041",
          "timeSlots": [
            {
              "_id": "5a934e0001020304340002",
              "spots": 3
            },
            {
              "_id": "5a934e000102030405672",
              "spots": 8
            },
            
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

for query I have:

1. bookingId
2. productId
3. timeSlotId

---

1. if only booking id matched then the query will return booking object, not other nested elements.
2. if bookingId and cart item that matched with productId then the query will return booking and cart object, timeSlotes will be ignored from nested document.
3. if bookingId, productId and timeSlotId all three matched then the query will return booking, cart, and associated timeslot

Answer (score 0):

query:

```
db.bookings.aggregate([{$match: {
 _id: '5a934e000102030405000000'
}}, {$addFields: {
 cart: {
  $filter: {
   input: '$cart',
   as: 'obj',
   cond: {
    $ne: [
     '$$obj.productId',
     '9934e00010203040500041'
    ]
   }
  }
 }
}}, {$addFields: {
 'cart.timeSlots': {
  $filter: {
   input: {
    $first: '$cart.timeSlots'
   },
   as: 'obj',
   cond: {
    $eq: [
     '$$obj._id',
     '5a934e00010203040540002'
    ]
   }
  }
 }
}}])
```

result:

```
{ _id: '5a934e000102030405000000',
  cart: 
   [ { _id: '5a934e000102030405000001',
       productId: '5934e00010203040500031',
       timeSlots: [ { _id: '5a934e00010203040540002', spots: 2 } ] } ] }
``
```